# In VSCode is there a way to not highlight the entire string when focused?

Tags: visual-studio-code, glsl

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdbAA.png)

I'm trying to work through some [GLSL](https://thebookofshaders.com/05/) code which I have in a multi-line string, as is the convention. However whenever I edit the code contained in the string it distractingly highlights the entire string whenever the cursor is within it. Is there a setting to turn off this highlighting behavior in VSCode?

Comment: you can change the highlight color to transparent or your background color in vscode settings

`"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editor.selectionBackground": "#135564",
    "editor.selectionHighlightBackground": "#135564"
},`